# How can you switch printer automatically depending on what's plugged in? Windows 10

Tags: laptop, printing, setup, default-settings, network-location

I have a Windows 10 laptop that will be using several printers of the same model across different locations. I'm aware that you can have Windows 10 switch the default printer automatically based on location but is it possible for it to be switched based on what printer is actively plugged in? This pc is for an elderly user that will be unable to print to anything besides what's printing to default.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest removing all the printers that won't be used.

Comment: This user lives in multiple locations and needs to have access to all printers.

Comment: I wanted to add that this is the owner of our company that's retiring. I'm trying to make this as hands off as possible on his end because he will lack the knowledge of managing his printers.